# Use Glimpse on Sillverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, glimpse

Is it possible to use glimpse on an Silverlight app or is it made for ASP only?

I tried searching something on their page on how to set up Glimpse for SL-Projects, but haven't found anything yet.

So, I've been wondering if anyone has set up Glimpse correctly. Has anyone tried it yet and can tell us, how its working so far?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't done anything specific for Silverlight. That said, if within your app, you are calling through to JS to make ajax calls, Glimpse will pick those up within the Ajax tab and if you are making calls to the server directly through the SL runtime, they will picked up in the history tab. So you should be able to get some pretty good information out.